# Laravel doesn't find command

Tags: php, laravel

I make

> php artisan make:command BackupDatabaseCommand --command="command:backupdb"

I also registered firmly
**app\Console\kernel.php**

```
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\BackupDatabaseCommand::class,
];
```

But even if you try to execute the command i get here

> The system cannot find the path specified.
>   I want to know how to solve it

Comment: how are you trying to run your command?

Comment: Can include class as `"App\Console\Commands\BackupDatabaseCommand",`

Comment: There should be no need to register them in app\Console\Kernel.php. Does your command show up when running `php artisan`?

Comment: `The system cannot find the path specified` might refer to PHP not being installed, you trying to execute the command outside of the directory where the `artisan` file is or your command is trying to access a file that is not found. We need to know which one it is really

Comment: it should be  this `\Commands\BackupDatabaseCommand::class,` not 
`\App\Console\Commands\BackupDatabaseCommand::class,`

Comment: @lagbox I try php artisan command:backupdb

Comment: @Rahul Is it in registration?

Comment: @kerbholz Can I do it without registering?

Comment: @apokryfos PHP is installed without problems

Comment: Yes, you can totally skip the Kernel registering part, all commands within the `app/Console/Commands` directory will automatically be registered with Artisan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is wrong Since you are already in `App\Console` directory  there is no need to specify `App\Console`  it should be this:

```
protected $commands = [
    Commands\BackupDatabaseCommand::class,
];
```

here is the image from my working project

[image]

Thanks

Comment: their path is not wrong (its the FQCN) and there is no `Commands` namespace in the root

Comment: This is ever worse, there is not `Commands` namespace in the root namespace.

Comment: There's no need to register commands in Kernel.php, they will be autoloaded. And it should be `Commands` as stated in the manual, not `\Commands`

Comment: i know you don't have to register command unless you need to schedule a command then you have to register else it will be auto-loaded by laravel.
since the op mentioned that he is trying to register the command the path he is providing is wrong.

Comment: @Jerodev if you run `php artisan make:command XYZCommand` then laravel  will generate a folder `Commands` inside `App\Console\`

Comment: @SalmanZafar yes and it creates the commands with `namespace App\Console\Commands;` not `namespace Commands;`

Comment: your answer will generate the **string**: `'Commands\BackupDatabaseCommand'` not `'App\Console\Commands\BackupDatabaseCommand'`

Comment: @lagbox not it will not i've been using this my project many times.

Comment: `echo \Commands\Blah::class` will  **always** print `Commands\Blah` because its a FQCN (no matter where that is ran in any context) ... now that you altered your answer to remove the `\\` it is now correct

Comment: you removed `\\` ... that makes the reference to a FQCN which is why it was wrong ... now that you removed that slash it is a correct reference

Comment: @lagbox yes i know in hurry i added  `\` the btw thanks it was my mistake.

Comment: I still don't understand why OPs path was wrong, the only explanation would be if they changed their default namespace from `App` to something else since they did reference it via `\App...` to indicate the root namespace

Answer (score 0):

To Create command

```
php artisan make:command BackupDatabaseCommand --command=command:backupdb
```

You can register command as:

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\BackupDatabaseCommand'
];
```

and you can run command using:

```
php artisan command:backupdb
```